# labelType not working on dijit/forms/select

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo, dijit.form

adding an option to the dijit/forms/select, which is like this,

`"<nav asdasd>"`

Since dijit/forms/select, uses labelType = "html" by default, I am setting the labelType to 'text' but even then the option is added as an HTML element.

HTML

```
<select id="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-props="labelType:'text'" style="width:150px;"></select>
```

Javascript (Dojo)

```
require([
"dojo/ready",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dijit/registry"], function (ready,lang,registry) {

ready(function () {

    var select1 = registry.byId("select1");

    option1 = {
        value: "o1",
        label: "option 1",
        selected: false
    };

    option2 = {
        value: "o2",
        label: "option 2",
        selected: true
    };

    option0 = {
        value: "o",
        label: "<nav asdasd>",
        selected: false
    };

    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option1));
    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option2));
    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option0));

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/gsbc25as/1/

Comment: The labelType is to tell the select how to handle the label coming back if you are using a dojo store to create the children.  In your case, you will have to escape your label.."&ltnav asdasd&gt"

Comment: @tik27, actually as far as I can tell, it applies to `options` too: http://jsfiddle.net/kqpk0wjt/ - that said, whether it works would depend on whether Sam007 is using Dojo 1.10 or not...

Comment: I am actually using 1.9 and that is where the issue was. Presently due to some constraints, I think I would need some escaping of strings to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your JSFiddle is running against Dojo 1.9.  If you switch to run against Dojo 1.10, it works as you'd expect.

The `labelType` property was only added in Dojo 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/registry"], function (
ready,
lang,
registry) {

    ready(function () {

        var select1 = registry.byId("select1");

      var  option1 = [
            {
            value: "o1",
            label: "option 1",
            selected: false
        },
            {
            value: "o2",
            label: "option 2",
            selected: false
        },
            {
            value: "o",
            label: "&ltnav Assad&gt",
        selected: true
    } ]

        select1.addOption(lang.clone(option1));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who wish to use Dojo 1.9 with the fix,

http://jsfiddle.net/gsbc25as/6/

```
require([
"dojo/ready",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dijit/registry",
"dojox/html/entities"], function (ready,lang,registry,entities) {

ready(function () {

    var select1 = registry.byId("select1");

    option1 = {
        value: "o1",
        label: "option 1",
        selected: false
    };

    option2 = {
        value: "o2",
        label: "option 2",
        selected: true
    };

    option0 = {
        value: "o",
        label: entities.encode("<nav asdasd>"),
        selected: false
    };

    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option1));
    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option2));
    select1.addOption(lang.clone(option0));

});
```

});